# ¿Agregar dos condiciones C?

Tags: c, condiciones, dev-c++

Lo que pretendo es hacer un programa en C, que me dé la nota final de una materia y dependiendo del nùmero, me muestre en pantalla un mensaje.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>

main (){

    float cal1=0, cal2=0, cal3=0, cal4=0;
    float notafinal=0;

    printf("Ingrese la Nota del 1er Corte:  \n\n");
    scanf("%f",&cal1);
    printf ("Ingrese la Nota del 2do Corte:  \n\n");
    scanf("%f",&cal2);
    printf("Ingrese la Nota del 3er Corte:  \n\n");
    scanf("%f",&cal3);
    printf("Ingrese la Nota del 4to Corte:  \n\n");
    scanf("%f",&cal4);

    notafinal=((cal1*0.2)+(cal2*0.2)+(cal3*0.3)+(cal4*0.4));

    if (notafinal > 18){
        printf ("\nYOUR A FUCKING GENIUS\n\n");
        printf ("Su nota es: %f\n\n",notafinal);
    }

    if (notafinal > 12){
        printf("\nAPROBADO\n\n");
        printf("Su nota es: %f\n\n",notafinal);
    }
    else {

        printf("\nREPROBADO\n\n");
        printf("Su nota es: %f\n\n",notafinal);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

El problema es que me muestra tanto el mensaje de aprobado como el mensaje de un **genio**, y quiero que solo me coloque el primero.

**Pseudocódigo:** Necesito traducir algo como esto pero en C.

```
Si notafinal > 12 escribir APROBADO, SU N...
Si notafinal < 12 escribir DESAPROBADO, SU N...
Si notafinal > 18 escribir GENIO, SU N.. (SIN ESCRIBIR APROBADO, SU NOTA ES...).
```

Comment: Amigo y si en vez de usar el if else usas el Swith

Answer (score 5):

No confundir :

- `if {...} if{...}` preguntará Siempre `dos` veces si la variable cumple con la condición (como es su caso) así la primera condición sea `verdadera`, por eso se da el mensaje erróneo porque comprueba que la nota sea mayor de `18` luego vuelve a preguntar si es mayor que `12`  las dos son verdaderas si la nota es 19 por ejemplo imprime doble mensaje
- `if{...} else if{...}` preguntará `dos` veces sí la primera condición del `if` no se cumple, en cambio si se cumple la primera  condición solo entrará ahí y ya no volverá a preguntar lo que está en el `else if()`

Modificar su `if` por un `else if` y tendría que funcionar muy bien. Teniendo en consideración que la validación del `>18` debe ir en el primer `if` y luego el `>12` en el `else if` si cambia el orden el algoritmo vuelve a fallar. y tendría que hacer uso de intervalos para la validación.

```
if (notafinal > 18){
     printf ("\nYOUR A FUCKING GENIUS\n\n");
     printf ("Su nota es: %f\n\n",notafinal);
}
else if (notafinal > 12 ){
     printf("\nAPROBADO\n\n");
     printf("Su nota es: %f\n\n",notafinal);
}
else {
     printf("\nREPROBADO\n\n");
     printf("Su nota es: %f\n\n",notafinal);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Propongo esto como solución:

```
int main()
{
    float cal1=0, cal2=0, cal3=0, cal4=0;
    float notafinal=0;

printf("Ingrese la Nota del 1er Corte:  \n\n");
scanf("%f",&cal1);
printf ("Ingrese la Nota del 2do Corte:  \n\n");
scanf("%f",&cal2);
printf("Ingrese la Nota del 3er Corte:  \n\n");
scanf("%f",&cal3);
printf("Ingrese la Nota del 4to Corte:  \n\n");
scanf("%f",&cal4);

notafinal=((cal1*0.2)+(cal2*0.2)+(cal3*0.3)+(cal4*0.4));

if (notafinal > 18)
{
    printf ("\nYOUR A FUCKING GENIUS\n\n");
    printf ("Su nota es: %f\n\n",notafinal);
}
else if(notafinal > 12)
{
    printf("\nAPROBADO\n\n");
    printf("Su nota es: %f\n\n",notafinal);
}
else
{

    printf("\nREPROBADO\n\n");
    printf("Su nota es: %f\n\n",notafinal);
}
 return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Debiera quedar de esta forma tu condición:

```
    if (notafinal > 12 && notafinal<=18){
        printf("\nAPROBADO\n\n");
        printf("Su nota es: %f\n\n",notafinal);
    }
    else if (notafinal <=12){
        printf("\nREPROBADO\n\n");
        printf("Su nota es: %f\n\n",notafinal);
}
```

Comment: rfrp gracias bro pero ahora me muestra el "Eres un Genio" y "Reprobado" jajaja.

Comment: @Romasanta revisa ahí

Answer (score 0):

Sencillo, solo debes agregar un return en el primer if de forma que si es un genio, ahi nomas termina. El codigo debe quedar asi:

```
    #include<stdio.h>
    #include<conio.h>

    main (){

    float cal1=0, cal2=0, cal3=0, cal4=0;
    float notafinal=0;

    printf("Ingrese la Nota del 1er Corte:  \n\n");
    scanf("%f",&cal1);
    printf ("Ingrese la Nota del 2do Corte:  \n\n");
    scanf("%f",&cal2);
    printf("Ingrese la Nota del 3er Corte:  \n\n");
    scanf("%f",&cal3);
    printf("Ingrese la Nota del 4to Corte:  \n\n");
    scanf("%f",&cal4);

    notafinal=((cal1*0.2)+(cal2*0.2)+(cal3*0.3)+(cal4*0.4));

    if (notafinal > 18){
        printf ("\nYOUR A FUCKING GENIUS\n\n");
        printf ("Su nota es: %f\n\n",notafinal);
        return 0;
    }

    if (notafinal > 12){
        printf("\nAPROBADO\n\n");
        printf("Su nota es: %f\n\n",notafinal);
    }
    else {

        printf("\nREPROBADO\n\n");
        printf("Su nota es: %f\n\n",notafinal);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Probablemente las soluciones anteriores funcionen, no las probé, pero de esta forma es lo que menos modifica a tú propio código.
Espero te ayude!

Answer (score 0):

Básicamente sería como ya te han dicho cambiar la secuencia `if... if...`por `if... else if... else...`. Veamos:

```
if (notafinal > 18){//Entra si es mayor que 18
    printf ("\nYOUR A FUCKING GENIUS\n\n");
    printf ("Su nota es: %f\n\n",notafinal);
}
else if (notafinal > 12){//Aquí te entraría si no ha entrado en el anterior,
    /*Es decir, si notafinal > 12 y <= 18
    *Si sólo pones if, entrará también ya que no importa 
    *la condición anterior, entra al ser mayor que 12
    */
    printf("\nAPROBADO\n\n");
    printf("Su nota es: %f\n\n",notafinal);
}
else {//Y aquí entra si no ha entrado en ninguno de los anteriores
    printf("\nREPROBADO\n\n");
    printf("Su nota es: %f\n\n",notafinal);
}

return 0;
```